Confusion in understanding phase lead/lag and its relation with path lead/lag
$Asin(kx-\omega t)$ is a wave travelling in the positive $x$ direction. The phase of oscillation of point $x$ is $(kx-\omega t)$ and that of point $(x+\delta x)$ is $(k(x+\delta x)-\omega t) = (kx-\omega t) + k\delta x$. This means that the phase of the second point is ahead of the phase of the first by $k\delta x$.
However the same wave $Asin(kx-\omega t)$ can also be written as $Asin(\omega t-kx+\pi)$. The phase of oscillation of point $x$ is $(\omega t-kx+\pi)$ and that of point $(x+\delta x)$ is $(\omega t -k(x+\delta x)+\pi) = (\omega t-kx+\pi) - k\delta x$. This means that the phase of the second point is behind the phase of the first by $k\delta x$.
In both the cases the second point is ahead of the first by a path difference of $\delta x$ which is assumed positive. But, according to the first wave equation, the second point leads in phase whereas according to the second wave equation the second point lags in phase. Can someone kindly help me make sense of these contradicting conclusions?

Can someone kindly help me make sense of these contradicting conclusions?
You need to consider what is wrong with your analysis by going back to first principles.
You are considering a wave traveling in the positive x-direction so here is a graph of displacement, $y$, against position, $x$, at two times, $t=0$ and $t=\delta t$.

Thus graphs of $y(t=0) =\sin (kx) $ and $y(t=\delta t) =\sin (kx-\omega \delta t)$ which are called wave profiles, essentially "photographs" of waves at instants of time.
From the graphs it should be clear that your statement, This means that the phase of the second point $[x+\delta x]$ is ahead of the phase of the first $[x]$ by kδx. is not correct.
In fact it is phase lag with whatever is happening at position $x$ being done later in time at position $x+\delta x$.
Now consider $y = \sin(\omega t-kx+\pi)$ at $t=0$, ie $y = \sin(-kx+\pi) = \sin (kx)$, no different from the previous example and so still a phase lag.
So what is wrong with your analysis?
Suppose you consider the peak of the wave.
At position $x$, $y=\sin (kx-\omega t)$ with $kx-\omega t_{\rm x} =  \pi /2 \Rightarrow t_{\rm x} = \frac{kx-\pi/2}{\omega}$.
At position $x+\delta x$, $y=\sin (k(x+\delta x)-\omega t)$ with $k(x+\delta x) -\omega t_{\rm x+\delta x} =  \pi /2 \Rightarrow t_{\rm x+\delta x} = \frac{kx+k\delta x -\pi/2}{\omega}$.
Thus $t_{\rm x+\delta x} > t_{\rm x}$ and so the peak is reached later at position $x+\delta x$ than at position $x$, ie the wave at position $x+\delta x$ lags behind the wave at position $x$.
Try the same analysis with $y=A\sin(\omega t - kx +\pi)$ and you should come to the same conclusion about the relative phases between positions $x$ and $x+\delta x$.
